# Logarithm of exponential

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

Ok, this is awkward.

```
E^Log[a]
```

gives `a`, which is what I expected, BUT,

```
Log[E^a]
```

is not evaluated at all (I expected the result to be `a`—this is actually an MWE, what I was trying to do was more complex).

Since I still struggle to understand some of Mathematica's concepts (like when expressions are/n't evaluated), I thought (wrongly, it seems) that it was an `Evaluate` or `Assumptions` issue, but now I think it wasn't. I tried:

```
Assuming[a ∈ Reals, Log[E^a]] // Evaluate
Assuming[a > 0, Log[Exp[a]]] // Simplify
```

and other variants—which in turn shows that I'm giving a shot in the dark.

What is the explanation for this behavior? How do I get to `a`? Am I missing an assumption? I don't really care about any weird special cases, `a` is real, not complex, nor a function, nor anything else.

It obviously seems that I'm missing something (possibly very simple and obvious), but I can't figure out what.

Comment: perhaps reading up on [`PowerExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand.html?q=PowerExpand) will help you achieve the desired goal

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log) is a multi-valued inverse function of [`Exp`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exp), Mathematica doesn't evaluate `Log[Exp[a]]` (or equivalently, `Log[E^a]`). If you want to simplify these, you need to provide an assumption on the domain of `a`, e.g.,

```
Simplify[Log[E^a], a ∈ Reals]
```

> a

or

```
Simplify[Log[E^a], a > 0]
```

> a

as suggested in the other answer. Another method is to use [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand):

```
PowerExpand[Log[E^a], Assumptions -> True]
```

> a + 2 I π Floor[1/2 - Im[a]/(2 π)]

**Addendum**

As an aside, [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log) behave exactly like [`ArcSin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcSin) here:

```
ArcSin[Sin[x]]
```

> ArcSin[Sin[x]]

Including a domain restriction:

```
Simplify[ArcSin[Sin[x]], -Pi/2 < x < Pi/2]
```

> x

For larger domains, [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) doesn't work:

```
Simplify[ArcSin[Sin[x]], 0 < x < 2 Pi]
```

> ArcSin[Sin[x]]

Again, using [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) is useful:

```
p = PowerExpand[ArcSin[Sin[x]], Assumptions -> 0 < x < 2Pi];
p //TeXForm
```

> $\begin{cases}
>  \pi -x & \frac{\pi }{2}<x\leq \frac{3 \pi }{2} \\
>  x & x\leq \frac{\pi }{2} \\
>  x-2 \pi  & \text{True}
> \end{cases}$

Visualization:

```
GraphicsColumn[{
    Plot[ArcSin[Sin[x]], {x, 0, 2 Pi}],
    Plot[p, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice explanation! Is there/Shouldn't there be a standard, single valued version of `Log`, just as the classical, ubiquitous `asin`, `acos`, `atan`? (I know this question may be beyond Mathematica). Is there a mathematical reason for the different treatment? Is it just for historic/convenience/arbitrary reasons?

Comment: @Rafael Log is a standard single valued function when given numerical input. When given symbolic input, Log is not able to figure out the right branch to use without assumptions. This is exactly how ArcSin etc, behave, e.g., ArcSin[Sin[x]] returns it's input.

Comment: I see, silly me. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

The assumption `a > 0` is needed when `Simplify` is called:

```
Assuming[a > 0, Log[Exp[a]] // Simplify]
```

> a

Comment: `a \[Element] Reals` works, too.  The problem with complex `a` is that `Log[Exp[a + 2 Pi I]]` and `Log[Exp[a]]` are equal.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a good reason why `Assuming[a > 0, Log[Exp[a]]]` won't just evaluate to `a`? I don't get it. (cc: @MichaelE2 )

Comment: @Rafael - The assumptions specified in `Assuming` only affect functions that take the option `Assumptions`. Neither `Log` nor `Exp` take options. You need to include `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` within the  `Assuming` for the assumptions to be used.

Comment: @BobHanlon, Ok, I see. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Logarithm is a problematic function for MMA. I do not know the reason. One can see, for example `Log[a] + Log[b] // Simplify` returns `Log[a] + Log[b]` though `LeafCount[Log[a] + Log[b]]` yields 5, while `LeafCount[Log[a*b]]` gives 4.

I do not think that in the case `Log[E^a]` we should use such conditions as `a>0` or whatever, since the relation in question is universal. On the other hand, in the case `Log[E^a]===a` the expression `a` is doubtless much simpler and, therefore, preferable. It is not that clear what one prefers to have in the case `Log[a] + Log[b]`

The way around can be using rules. For example, in this case one may use

```
rule = Log[x_^y_] :> y*Log[x];
```

Then its application gives

```
In[5]:= Log[E^a] /. rule

  (*   Out[5]= a *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Would you say you disagree with the other answers, then? I'd love to read more debate on the issue, if it is somehow contentious

Comment: @Rafael No, I do not. However, they used some conditions imposed on `a` to achieve the desired results. We know, however, that the relation `Log[Exp[a]]===a` holds for any `a`. So, using the relation, say, `a>0` is to extent misleading. Indeed, in this case, we know that it holds for any `a`. However, in a more cumbersome case this condition may lead you into an erroneous assumption that such an inequality is necessary. Anyway, one should be careful.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch the expression isn't general for complex values of `a`. `a > 0` forces `a` into the reals. Also, consider `a = -1 + I`, `b=-1`; the sum of the logs is not the log of the product.

Comment: @Davidmh My word "universal" relates to the identity `Log[Exp[a]]===a`.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch sorry, I was unclear. I should have split my comment: `Log[Exp[a]]===a` isn't general for complex values of `a` (in particular, when `Abs[Im[a]] > 2 Pi`), but `a > 0` forces `a` into the reals. Furthermore, `Log[a] + Log[b]` is not, in general, `Log[a*b]` if `a` or `b` are complex.

Comment: `In[33]:= Log[Exp[a]] /. a->-1-5*I                                               

Out[33]= (-1 - 5 I) + (2 I) Pi` So this claimed identity is simply wrong. As has been noted in the comment by @Davidmh